# IAM users and last login date in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to pull the list of IAM users from google cloud along with their last activity??

Tried "gcloud projects get-iam-policy"

but it gives only list of iam users/members but not their last activity

Comment: Why do you need that? Is that for your company? Do you have a Google Cloud Identity domain? A GCP organization?

Comment: Yes, its for company on cleanup activity.  We dont have GCP organization

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if it's for company, you have this information in the Google Cloud Identity platform. You can log in here: https://admin.google.com

Go to users and boom

[image]

Of course you can request these values by API with the [admin sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk)

*It works only for managed accounts. If you have unmanaged account (in gmail.com or from another company) you don't have access to this information.*

---

**EDIT 1**

To track the service account activity, you can rely on [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-monitoring). Cloud Monitoring allow you to do that. If you need to export the data to BigQuery for analytics for example, let me know I could help on that.

To know the privilege that the users have, you can rely on the [Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory), and especially on the IAM search policy feature.

Comment: This seems only for google workspace, not GCP.

Comment: Yes it's for managed account on Workspace, it doesn't work for not managed account, such as gmail account.

Comment: I am not really talking about a gmail account. I am talking about users that have IAM access to a GCP account. It's not in "Workspace", which is the new name for "G Suite" and "Google Apps for Your Domain", and the constant renaming is unhelpful. But it's bad that we don't have that simple basic crucial feature in GCP IAM and Service Accounts.

Comment: You can track the service account activity, but not the user activity. What is your use case around the user activity?

Comment: How can we track service accounts? Those are the most pressing. With user accounts, it's more about just understanding who is using the privilege.

Comment: I updated my answer (those pointers can help many people)