# GCP logging: Find all resources (recently) used by a specific user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

This is part of my journey to get a clear overview of which users/service accounts are in my GCP Project and when they last logged in.
Endgoal: to be able to clean up users/service-accounts if needed when they weren't on GCP for a long time.

First question:
How can I find in the logs when a specific user used resources, so I can determine when this person last logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Auditlogs and to see them you can run the following query in Cloud Logging:

```
protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="your_user_name_email_or_your_service_account_email"
```

You can also check the Activity logs and filter on a user:
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

Related questions + answers:
[Pull "last access" information on projects from Google Cloud Platform (GCP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267145/pull-last-access-information-on-projects-from-google-cloud-platform-gcp)
[IAM users and last login date in google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215010/iam-users-and-last-login-date-in-google-cloud)
[How to list, find, or search iam policies across services (APIs), resource types, and projects in google cloud platform (GCP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480678/how-to-list-find-or-search-iam-policies-across-services-apis-resource-types)

Answer (score 1):

There is now also the newly added Log Analytics.
This allows you to use SQL to query your logs.

Your logging buckets _Default and _Required need to be upgraded to be able to use Log Analytics:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#upgrade-bucket

After that you use for example the console to use SQL on your logs:
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/analytics

Unfortunately, at the moment you can only query the logs that were created after you've switched on Log Analytics.

Example query in the Log Analytics:

```sql
SELECT
  timestamp, 
  proto_Payload.audit_log.authentication_info.principal_email, 
  auth_info.resource,
  auth_info.permission,
  auth_info.granted
FROM
  `logs__Default_US._AllLogs` 
    left join unnest(proto_Payload.audit_log.authorization_info) auth_info
WHERE
  timestamp > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  and proto_payload.type = "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
  and proto_Payload.audit_log.authentication_info.principal_email in ("name_of_your_user")
ORDER BY 
  timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND
resource.type="project" AND
protoPayload.serviceName="cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com" AND
protoPayload.methodName="SetIamPolicy" AND
protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action="Add" AND
protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.member:"EMAIL_ID"
```

See here for more examples.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library